# How do I downsample a control rate variable to a scalar value?

Tags: supercollider

In SuperCollider: How do I downsample a control rate variable to a scalar value?

For instance, I have a scalar global called ~delay and a few functions care about that value. They assume it is a scalar. I wanted to set a envelope generator on that variable in order to change it via a control rate variable. Or use MouseX.kr, if I could convert a single value of MouseX.kr to a scalar value I would be happy.

Assume that I cannot refactor the code to allow for a k-rate global and thus I need to sample or downsample a single value from a control rate variable.

I can't do this:

```
    MouseX.kr(1, 4, 1).rand.wait;
```

But I'd be happy with this:

```
    downSample(MouseX.kr(1, 4, 1)).rand.wait;
```

Or

```
    ~mousex = MouseX.kr(1, 4, 1)
    ...
    downSample(~mousex).rand.wait
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the classic [SuperCollider **language-vs-server**](http://doc.sccode.org/Guides/ClientVsServer.html) issue. You want to use MouseX (which represents the server's knowledge of mouse position) in a language-side calculation. ("Why the split? Why can't the language know it using the same object?" - well, imagine the two processes are running on different machines - different mice...)

To get the mouse position in the language, it's better to use one of:

```
 Platform.getMouseCoords  // SC up to 3.6
 GUI.cursorPosition // SC recent versions
```

If you're sure you want to use server data in the language, then your own answer about sending via a [Bus](http://doc.sccode.org/Classes/Bus.html) is one way to do it. Recent versions of SuperCollider have methods

```
 Bus.getSynchronous
 Bus.setSynchronous
```

which rely on the new "shared memory interface" between language and server. If the two are on the same machine, then this can be a nice way to do it which avoids the latency of asynchronously requesting the info.

Answer (score 0):

After much research I came up with 1 solution: use a control Bus to grab values. We take a function as input (f) and then play it to a bus.

We then read from that bus by calling the get method on the bus and providing function that allows us to extract the value from the function thrown in.

```
    ~mkscalarfun = {
        arg f={ 0 };
        var last = 0.0;
        var mbus = Bus.control(s, 1);   
        var pf = f.play(s,mbus);
        var scalarf = {
            mbus.get({|v| last = v;});
            last;
        };
        scalarf; // This is a function
    };
    // Create a closure that includes the bus
    ~mousescalarf = ~mkscalarfun.({ MouseX.kr(1,  4, 1); });
    ~mousescalarf.();
    ~mousescalarf.().rand.wait;
```

I am not sure how idiomatic this solution or if it is appropriate or how well it performs.

One problem with this solution is that pf is hidden and thus you can't stop it.

One alternative is to use an OO solution where you make a class in your extension directory:

```
    MakeScalarKR {
        var last;
        var mbus;
        var pf;
        var f;
        *new { arg sbase,f;
            ^super.new.init(sbase,f)
        }
        init { 
            arg sbase,myf;
            f = myf;
            last = 0.0;
            mbus = Bus.control(sbase, 1);   
            pf = f.play(sbase, mbus);
        }
        v {
            mbus.get({|x| last=x;});
            ^last
        }
        free {
            pf.free
        }
    }
```

Then you can invoke this class like so:

```
    ~mkr = MakeScalarKR(s,{ MouseX.kr(10,400,1) });
    ~mkr.v()
```